# Integrate python-social-auth (social-app-django) to be used with the Django admin

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I want to create an app that uses the django admin, but allows logins via google (my company google account) in place of the django default ModelAdmin.

Currently, it looks like [social-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) (*google*) is the way to go, but after having installed and setup a project, it's not clear to me how I can allow django admin logins to use the [social-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) authentication.  I've attempted to configure my project as described here http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html but it isn't clear how this can be integrated with the django admin.

I found this [snippit](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2856/) (which seems *out-of-date*), and added it, but get a 404 when I try to goto `/admin/`:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/admin/login/%3Fnext%3D/admin/
>   Using the URLconf defined in telos.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order: ^login/(?P[^/]+)/$ [name='begin']
>   ^complete/(?P[^/]+)/$ [name='complete']
>   ^disconnect/(?P[^/]+)/$ [name='disconnect']
>   ^disconnect/(?P[^/]+)/(?P[^/]+)/$
>   [name='disconnect_individual'] ^admin/ The current path,
>   accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.

If I remove the snippit, `/admin/` will redirect to `/admin/login/` and on login attempt return the ERROR text:

> Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account.
>   Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

In addition to the [configuration](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html), I've added the following to my `settings.py`:

**projects/models.py (MyUser)**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

**settings.py**

```
# for identification of SOCIAL_AUTH_USER
# http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/settings.html#user-model
SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'projects.MyUser'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'projects.MyUser'  # not sure if this is needed
```

Can anyone direct me on how I can setup my project to allow me to login to the django admin through [social-app-django](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django) (*google*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django Admin uses the `auth` contrib application, so any authentication process triggers the same mechanism than a user logging in to a non-admin section and it will be processed by `python-social-auth` backends if they are defined in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting.

In order to make it work you will need to:

1. Add a `Login with Google` link (linking to `/login/google-oauth2`) to the login form. You can override the default login form by adding a [admin/login.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/login.html) template or by defining a custom [AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects)
2. Ensure that the user is flagged as `is_staff`, otherwise access to the admin will be forbidden.

Comment: had to work out how to override the template, etc..  but got it working. Thanks!